# Using AWK to filter csv data by column values, with wildcards

Tags: awk, wildcard

I have a csv file that contains lines such as

```
      1          Er6          Te100      7.02455       1   0   0           -0.00420 
      2          Cu7          S150       6.96222       0  -1   0           -0.00421 
      3          Sc8          P50        7.01955       0   0   0           -0.00397
```

I would like to use awk to filter the data and display rows that

1. have their second column having values of Cu* and the third column having values of S* or Te*

OR

2. have their second column having values of S* or Te* and the third column having values of Cu*

So far, I am building the command up from its simplest form and is stuck at

```
awk '{ if (($2 == "Cu*")) { print } }' file
```

This does not output anything. It seems that "Cu*" is not recognized by AWK as a wildcard, hence there is no match.

I'm also unsure how to deliver the OR statement that contains two and statements.

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: your data contains no commas so not really "CSV". If it actually does contain comma separators, your command will need `-F,`. If escaped or quoted commas can appear, then a more sophisticated command will be needed

Comment: awk does not use globs. `==` is string equality comparison. Use `~` for regex comparison.

Comment: awk commands take format `pattern { action }` (if pattern then action). default action is print. so: `awk '($2~/^Cu/ && $3~/^(S|Te)/) || ($2~/^(S|Te)/ && $3~/^Cu/)' inputfile`

Comment: You're trying to use bash syntax in an awk script - you may as well try to use bash syntax in a C program. bash and awk are 2 completely different tools with their own language syntax and semantics, with awk's syntax being far more similar to C than to bash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I post this as an answer for the sake of formatting, but jhnc should get the "win" for this question,  I think.

An awk script, whether in a file or a one-liner is made up of sets of `condition { statement }` which are evaluated for every line of input. A blank condition is equivalent to `true`, and a blank statement is equivalent to `{ print }`. Thus, if your intended action is just to print, your statement can be dropped, and if you're just evaluating patterns, your `if` can be dropped and the `condition` moved to its proper place.

You've got a one-liner already. Know that it can be stored in a file as well:

```
$ cat test.awk

($2~/^Cu/ && $3~/^(S|Te)/) ||
($2~/^(S|Te)/ && $3~/^Cu/)

$ awk -f test.awk input.txt
      2          Cu7          S150       6.96222       0  -1   0           -0.00421
```

As you can see, I've put your conditions on separate lines for easier reading in case the list grows. Taken altogether, it's still a single awk condition which, if it evaluates as true, takes the default action and prints the line. That said, take care when splitting lines. This script still works because `||` is at the end of the line, so awk knows the condition continues. Placing the `||` at the beginning of the next line would be an error.

I don't know if your input dataset includes possible false positives with these patterns. For example `/^s/` would match `S150` but also `Se10`. If you want to make sure that the letters you're matching are always followed by non-letters, you could use conditions like this:

```
($2~/^Cu[^[:alpha:]]/ && $3~/^(S|Te)[^[:alpha:]]/) ||
($2~/^(S|Te)[^[:alpha:]]/ && $3~/^Cu[^[:alpha:]]/)
```

This may seem cumbersome, and is not the only way to do this, but is perhaps worth the mention. If words in these columns will always have numbers after them, you could replace the character class match `[^[:alpha:]]` with `[0-9]`.

Comment: if you break lines for clarity, you need to be careful how you do it. consider: `echo hello | awk $'/world/\n{print "ok"}\n'`

Comment: Thanks @ghoti, your discussion on the false positives is very helpful. I was thinking about how to deal with them as well and now we have the answer here.

Comment: @jhnc, that's an excellent point. I've added a warning and explanation why it works in this case. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You may combine all the conditions like this in singe expression:

```bash
awk '($2 ~ /^Cu/ && $3 ~ /^(S|Te)/) || ($2 ~ /^(S|Te)/ && $3 ~ /^Cu/)' file

      2          Cu7          S150       6.96222       0  -1   0           -0.00421
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat file
1          Er6          Te100      7.02455       1   0   0           -0.00420 
2          Cu7          S150       6.96222       0  -1   0           -0.00421 
3          Sc8          P50        7.01955       0   0   0           -0.00397 
4          Sc9          Cu30       7.01955       0   0   0           -0.00397 
5          Te200        Cu20       7.01955       0   0   0           -0.00397 
6          Cu7          P50        6.96222       0  -1   0           -0.00421
7          Cu7          Te40       6.96222       0  -1   0           -0.00421
```

Assuming that only field 2 and field 3 are strings and all other fields are numbers

```
$ awk -F' Cu.* (S|Te)| (S|Te).* Cu' 'NF==2' file
2          Cu7          S150       6.96222       0  -1   0           -0.00421 
4          Sc9          Cu30       7.01955       0   0   0           -0.00397 
5          Te200        Cu20       7.01955       0   0   0           -0.00397
7          Cu7          Te40       6.96222       0  -1   0           -0.00421
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use [globs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) instead of [awk regular expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Regexp-Operator-Details.html) the easiest way is probably with Ruby:

```
ruby -lane '
BEGIN{ def fnm(glob, string) File.fnmatch(glob, string) end}
puts $_ if (fnm("Cu*", $F[1]) && (fnm("S*", $F[2]) || fnm("Te*", $F[2]))) || 
            ((fnm("S*", $F[1]) || fnm("Te*", $F[1])) && fnm("Cu*", $F[2]))
' file
```

Prints:

```
      2          Cu7          S150       6.96222       0  -1   0           -0.00421
```

Perl and Python support CSV and globs agains strings also.